# How to find Mac OSX UID from Ubuntu

Tags: macos, permissions, mount, user-accounts, uid

How do you view Mac OSX user id without having to boot into OSX? I can mount the drive, but I can't find the UID for my user, which would hopefully enable me to access files without being root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer here. This is the UID that's tied to the user account.

According to [this article](http://www.defenceindepth.net/2011/09/cracking-os-x-lion-passwords.html), the user information can be found in this file

```
/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/{user-name}.plist
```

I verified and the UID was at the bottom of the file, in my case. There's also some business about a generateduid, but that's not what you want, so ignore that.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check who owns your home directory, using `stat /mnt/Users/weberc2` for example. This is the UID that actually matters, anyway.

Comment: That's helpful, but I would like to know the UID of my account as well, in case they are different. I already figured that out and posted the corresponding answer. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: They are almost never different; files that you create are owned by you.

Comment: Yep. Long story, but my circumstances required me to check both. I voted up your answer because it was helpful.